# libpcap read packet size

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I started to write an application which will read RTP/H.264 video packets from an existing .pcap file, I need to read the packet size.
I tried to use **packet->len or header->len**, but it never displays the right number of bytes for packets (I'm using **wireshark** to verify packet size - under Length column). How to do it? 
This is part of my code:

```
while (packet = pcap_next(handle,&header)) {

  u_char *pkt_ptr = (u_char *)packet;
  struct ip *ip_hdr = (struct ip *)pkt_ptr; //point to an IP header structure 
  struct pcap_pkthdr  *pkt_hdr =(struct pcap_pkthdr *)packet;

  unsigned int packet_length = pkt_hdr->len;
  unsigned int ip_length = ntohs(ip_hdr->ip_len);
  printf("Packet # %i IP Header length: %d bytes, Packet length: %d bytes\n",pkt_counter,ip_length,packet_length);


Packet # 0 IP Header length: 180 bytes, Packet length: 104857664 bytes
Packet # 1 IP Header length: 52 bytes, Packet length: 104857600 bytes
Packet # 2 IP Header length: 100 bytes, Packet length: 104857600 bytes
Packet # 3 IP Header length: 100 bytes, Packet length: 104857664 bytes
Packet # 4 IP Header length: 52 bytes, Packet length: 104857600 bytes
Packet # 5 IP Header length: 100 bytes, Packet length: 104857600 bytes
```

Another option I tried is to use:
pkt_ptr-> I get:

read_pcapfile.c:67:43: error: request for member ‘len’ in something not a structure or union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> while (packet = pcap_next(handle,&header)) {
>
>   u_char *pkt_ptr = (u_char *)packet;
> ```

Don't do that; you're throwing away the `const`, and you really should *NOT* be modifying what the return value of `pcap_next()` points to.

> ```
>   struct ip *ip_hdr = (struct ip *)pkt_ptr; //point to an IP header structure
> ```

That will point to an IP header structure *ONLY* if `pcap_datalink(handle)` returns `DLT_RAW`, which it probably will *NOT* do on most devices.

If, for example, `pcap_datalink(handle)` returns `DLT_EN10MB`, `packet` will point to an *Ethernet* header (the `10MB` is historical - it's used for all Ethernet speeds other than the ancient historical 3MB experimental Ethernet at Xerox, which had a different header type).

See [the list of link-layer header type values](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) for a list of the possible `DLT_` types.

> ```
>   struct pcap_pkthdr  *pkt_hdr =(struct pcap_pkthdr *)packet;
> ```

That won't work, either.  The `struct pcap_pkthdr` for the packet is in `header`.

> ```
>   unsigned int packet_length = pkt_hdr->len;
> ```

As per my earlier comment, that won't work.  Use `header.len` instead.

(And bear in mind that, if a "snapshot length" shorter than the maximum packet size was specified in the `pcap_open_live()` call, or specified in a `pcap_set_snaplen()` call between the `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` calls, `header.caplen` could be less than `header.len`, and only `header.caplen` bytes of the packet data will actually be available.)

> ```
>   unsigned int ip_length = ntohs(ip_hdr->ip_len);
> ```

And, as per my earlier comment, that probably won't work, either.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `header.len`.

```
unsigned int packet_length = header.len;
```